# Splicing type signature in template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to create a type signature for a function in template haskell. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I've done some workarounds to solve it in the meantime, but it should be easier, right?

```
-- TH.hs
module Lib.TH (mkFunction) where

import Language.Haskell.TH

mkFunction n = do
  let name = mkName n
  [d|
    $( ... ) :: Integer -> Integer
    $(varP name) = \x -> x + 2|]

-- Other.hs
import TH

mkFunction "test"
```

What should I write in the `$( ... )` above? Everything I've tried results in

```
Invalid type signature: ... :: Integer -> Integer
Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

Comment: This may not be satisfying but you can do `$(varP name) = (\x -> x + 2) :: Integer -> Integer`

Comment: I've tried, but unfortunately I need a constraint `(T a) => a -> a`, and it doesn't work if I include that.

Comment: I submitted a GHC feature request to add support for splicing `Name`s into type signatures in TH decl quotes: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15298

Answer (score 4):

I am no TH expert, but I found a way by digging around in the docs and following the type errors.

```
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

mkFunction n = do
    let name = mkName n
    [d|
        $( return . SigD name <$> [t| Integer -> Integer |] )
        $(varP name) = \x -> x + 2 |]
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way.

**NOTE** this works on 7.8.3 but not 7.10.2.  :-(

Comment: With 7.10.2, it throws this compile error: `Splices within declaration brackets not (yet) handled by Template Haskell` ?

Comment: @Sibi, that's too bad.  Worksforme at 7.8.3, a regression perhaps.  Anyway I edited my answer with an alternative phrasing that might work around this?  Can you try?

Comment: @Sibi, Nuts, I'm out of ideas.  Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't *think* (guess) there is a way to splice the name in a Template Haskell type   signature (for GHC ≤ 7.10).  To still use the quasi-quoting, you can try to process the AST afterwards to set the name where appropriate (and leave the rest untouched):

```
setName :: Name -> DecsQ -> DecsQ
setName = fmap . map . sn
  where sn n (SigD _ t)          = SigD n t
        sn n (ValD (VarP _) x y) = ValD (VarP n) x y
        sn _ d                   = d

mkFunction n = setName (mkName n)
  [d|
    n :: Integer -> Integer
    n = \x -> x + 2 |]
```

This was tested on GHC 7.10, and will probably work on past and future versions of GHC with minor modifications.

To what extent this is less or more verbose than writing the AST directly is arguable.  It will depend on the frequency you write declarations like that and the complexity of the quoted code.

The above `setName` function will obviously break if you use it on a declaration with multiple functions (or recursive functions).  To tackle that, you could write a `reName` function in the same spirit.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround. Using applicative syntax and refactoring [@luqui's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279198/470844) you get something close to what you want:

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

mkFunction n = do
    let name = mkName n
    (:) <$> name `sigD` [t| Integer -> Integer |]
        <*> [d| $(varP name) = \x -> x + 2 |]
```